# How to add and/or as part of the string to query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Some of my keywords contain **and/or**. The string query I made breaks when I use that data. My string queries need to be able to handle that data within its queries

Here is my query and error:

**Query:**

```
POST /test/_doc
{
  "keyword":"pizza oven and/or pizza"
}

GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "keywords.english",
            "query": "(pizza oven and/or pizza) OR (bread)"
          }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
  {
    "shard": 0,
    "index": "test",
    "node": "V3XGiCPAS0ej2PmYuk12qw",
    "reason": {
      "type": "query_shard_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse query [(pizza oven and/or pizza) OR (bread)]",
      "index_uuid": "OXSS-p_DTqeddnFkSjwWOw",
      "index": "test",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "parse_exception: Cannot parse '(pizza oven and/or pizza) OR (bread)': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"/or pizza) OR (bread)\"",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "token_mgr_error",
          "reason": "token_mgr_error: Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"/or pizza) OR (bread)\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I make that the **and/or** doesn't break the string query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` is a [reserved character](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) in the query string query language, you need to escape it:

```
        "query": "(pizza oven and\/or pizza) OR (bread)"
                                 ^
                                 |
```